# JVM Datasource tuning idle database connection in the connection pool for tomEE

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jvm, datasource, apache-tomee

I am trying to figure out if my Datasource definition is the root cause for an issue we are having. Our application stack in AWS has several TomEE machines running together behind and ELB. Randomly machines with retain idle connections to the database and not terminate.

I am wanting to know what we can do to better setup our connections and reaping of connections. Our application does have a moderate number of requests /sec.

Here is our Tomee.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
<!-- see http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html -->
<!-- Datasources for Prod -->   
   <Resource id="DBWPC" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
      DataSourceCreator tomcat
      JdbcDriver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      JdbcUrl jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.com:1521:service
      UserName xxxxx   
      Password xxxx
      jmxEnabled true
      InitialSize 5
      MaxActive 20
      MaxIdle 20
      MinIdle 0
      MaxWait -1
      ValidationQuery SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
      PoolPreparedStatements true
      MaxOpenPreparedStatements 0
      TestWhileIdle true
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis 180000
      JtaManaged true      
   </Resource>
 <!-- Standard JMS Setup for NON-SERVER **** START **** -->
 <Resource id="PrimaryJMSRA" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
            BrokerXmlConfig=
          ServerUrl = tcp://x.x.com:61616
  </Resource>
  <Resource id="JmsConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
            ResourceAdapter = PrimaryJMSRA
    </Resource>
 <Container id="JmsMdbContainer" ctype="MESSAGE">
    ResourceAdapter = PrimaryJMSRA
</Container>
<Container id="wpcStatelessContainer" type="STATELESS">
 accessTimeout = 30 seconds
 callbackThreads = 5
 closeTimeout = 5 minutes
 garbageCollection = false
 idleTimeout = 0 minutes
 maxAge = 0 hours
 maxAgeOffset = -1
 maxSize = 5000
 minSize = 20
 replaceAged = true
 replaceFlushed = false
 strictPooling = false
 sweepInterval = 5 minutes
 </Container>
 <Container id="wpcSingletonContainer" type="SINGLETON">
    accessTimeout = 30 seconds
</Container>
```

Comment: I should add that the issue that it is causing in the database is blocking sessions for other SIDs. We have had instance were we have over 200 session blocked by idle SIDs causing our application to stop responding. Like the JVM won't service another request because its waiting indefinitely I presume.

Answer (score 0):

Optimization depends on a lot of probable workloads and hence this may not be a final answer but an attempt. New sessions blocked/queued indicates that you do not have enough room to pool your connections. If you see a lot of connections to be created in the beginning, then increase your InitialSize from 5 to probably 20. Since you said 200 sessions, it is advisable to set your max active to 100 or 150 assuming you have a lot of concurrent sessions to be accommodated.

Try sample settings below (considering you need high concurrency) and let me know if it helps:

- testWhileIdle="true"
- testOnBorrow="true"
- testOnReturn="false"
- validationQuery="SELECT 1"
- validationInterval="30000"
- timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"
- maxActive="100"
- minIdle="10"
- maxIdle="20"
- maxWait="10000"
- initialSize="20"
- removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
- removeAbandoned="true"
- logAbandoned="true"
- minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"

Why I suggested these settings? Check link below:
http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency